# How can you factor this portion of the equation

Tags: factoring

This is a part of another person's question that was answered in [the first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390170/proof-of-inequality-without-calculus) . I was confused on how they took $3x+4y+xy=2012$ and factored it out to $(y+3)(x+4)=2024$. If someone could explain this to me that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general,
suppose
$xy + ax + by = c$.
Since
$(x+b)(y+a)
=xy+ax+by+ab
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(x+b)(y+a)
&=xy + ax + by+ab \\
&= c+ab\\
\end{array}
$.

Therefore,
$(x+b)$
and
$(y+a)$
are divisors of
$c+ab
$.
By looking at all the divisors
of $c+ab$,
you can find all possible values
of $x$ and $y$.

In your problem,
$a=3$,
$b=4$,
and
$c = 2012$,
so that
$c+ab
= 2012+3\cdot 4
=2024
$.

Look at all the factors of
$2024$
and,
for each $m$ and $n$
such that
$m\cdot n = 2024$,
set
$x+4 = n$
and
$y+3 = m$.

Comment: Thank you. Now this make a lot more sense

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{l} 
3x + 4y +xy = 2012\\
3x + 4y + xy + 12 = 2012 + 12\quad\quad\quad{\text{added 12 to both sides}}\\
\color{blue}{3x}+ \color{red}{4y}+\color{blue}{xy}+\color{red}{12} = 2024\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad{\text{factoring by grouping}}\\
x\cdot(3+y)+4\cdot(y+3) = 2024\quad\quad\quad\;\text{common factor $(y+3)$}\\
(x+4)(y+3) = 2024
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Where does the 12 come from. Is it just there because it is a multiple of 4 and 3?

Comment: Yes, so we can factorize by grouping.

Comment: OK thank you for the info

Comment: How also do you receive only one common factor of y plus 3

Comment: Consider $(y+3) = z$. Then, we would have $x \cdot z + 4 \cdot z = 2024$. Factoring out $z$  leads to $ z\cdot (x+4) = 2024$. Making again the substitution $z = (y+3)$ leads us to the last line.

Comment: The last portion seems to be part code. By the by thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Now I can read it and this is much simpler than above but both are good examples.

Comment: That's the essence! Total understanding, no matter the way! :)